# Symfony 3 - Get choices option from entity object passed to the form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have a `WorkflowType` form class which `data_class` attribute is `Workflow::class`. When creating the form in a Controller action function I pass it an `Workflow` object **which has a `states` property**:

```
public function createWorkflowAction(Request $request, Workflow $workflow) {
    $secondFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowType::class, $workflow);
    ...
}
```

To the form I add an `EntityType` form field which `class` attribute is `State::class`. This entity class has more then one property but I am just using one of it and want to render the `EntityType` field as a select box:

```
class WorkflowType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        //@formatter:off
            $builder
                ->add('initialState', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class'             => State::class,
                    'choice_label'      => 'key',
                    'choice_value'      => 'key',

                    // This combination of 'expanded' and 'multiple' implements a select box
                    'expanded'          => false,
                    'multiple'          => false,
                ))...
                ...
        }
        ...
}
```

Now the **problem**:

> Symfony tries to get the `choices` for `initialState` `EntityType` field out of the Database: `An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0_.id AS id_0, t0_.key AS key_1, t0_.order AS order_2, t0_.workflow_id AS workflow_id_3 FROM testpra_State t0_'`.
>
> But I want to get the `choices` from the `states` property of the `Workflow` object `$workflow`I pass to `createForm` in the controller.

Something like:

```
->add('initialState', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'             => State::class,
    'choice_label'      => 'key',
    'choice_value'      => 'key',
    'choices'           => $workflow->getStates(),

    // This combination of 'expanded' and 'multiple' implements a select box
    'expanded'          => false,
    'multiple'          => false,
))
```

**I know that I can use the `$option` array like:**

```
$secondFormPart = $this->createForm(PraWorkflowTransitionsType::class, $workflow, array(
    'states'    => $workflow->getStates()
));
```

But is there a simpler solution?

And if yes how can I get access to the object I pass to `createForm` in a subform?

Comment: Why don't you use ChoiceType if you want to provide choices already? also your object is located in `$options['data']` inside of your `buildForm`

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Because `initialState` is a property of type `State` of a `Workflow` entity... And so all choices shoulb be of type `State`. Does this work with `ChoiceType` ? If yes, then how?
Thank, just what I was looking for...

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices with Choice type you can add choices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ## But is there a simpler solution?

Like [kunicmarko20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5258172/kunicmarko20) stated in a comment the object is accessible through `$options['data']`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    /** @var Workflow $workflow */
    $workflow = $options['data'];
    ...
}
```

He also pointed out that I should use `ChoiceType` which is better because `EntityType` is [*designed to load options from a Doctrine entity*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

> ## And if yes how can I get access to the object I pass to createForm in a subform?

In my case I have a `CollectionType` field which dynamically adds forms of `entry_type` `TransitionType`. In this case you can pass the data via the `entry_options` attribute:

```
->add('transitions', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'        => TransitionType::class,
    'entry_options'     => array(
        'states'    => $workflow->getStates(),
    ),
    ...
))
```

and in the `TransitionType` class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    /** @var ArrayCollection $states */
    $states = $options['states'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please describe what is wrong about this solution?

Comment: I was not the original downvoter, but I find a few issues with solution presented. First of all, `$options['data']` is not guaranteed to be filled (i.e. no object might be passed, relying on `empty_data` option to populate it later). Second, you're selecting states instead of transitions, which are the purpose of using workflow in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

So You must pass an array to the form

```
public function createWorkflowAction(Request $request, Workflow $workflow) {
    $secondFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowType::class,null,array('workflow'=>$workflow));
    ... }
```

and add the option to the resolver

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Workflow',
        'workflow' => ''
    ));
}
```

then it will be accessible by $options['workflow'] not $workflow

Comment: I downvoted because 1. I allready said that I know that I can pass an variable in the options array and 2. [kunicmarko20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5258172/kunicmarko20) allready said that the object is located under `$options['data']` which means that in your answer you have the object twice in the form class which is even worse than my suggestion...